# log_format has no effect in Nginx Docker image

Tags: nginx

I'm setting the following in the http-level config in my Nginx configs, but it seems to be getting ignored. Maybe I'm missing something?

My [original] nginx.conf:

```
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent UCT=$upstream_connect_time UHT=$upstream_header_time URT=$upstream_response_time RT=$request_time "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    # Symlinked to /dev/stdout in the upstream Nginx image
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

My [original] server.conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    sendfile on;
    client_max_body_size 20M;
    keepalive_timeout 10;

    location /css {
        root /static;
    }

    location /images {
        root /static;
    }

    location /static {
        root /static;
    }

    location / {
        include uwsgi_params;

        uwsgi_read_timeout 120s;
        uwsgi_send_timeout 120s;

# TODO(dustin): Until we can figure this out in the context of ECS.
#        uwsgi_pass unix:/shared/sellback_website.sock;
        uwsgi_pass sellback-website-app:8000;
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:latest

ADD config/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
ADD config/server.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

The contents/format of the access-log given the above config:

```
10.0.2.57 - - [13/Jun/2022:05:00:05 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.3.211 - - [13/Jun/2022:05:00:33 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.1.78 - - [13/Jun/2022:05:00:33 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
10.0.2.57 - - [13/Jun/2022:05:00:34 +0000] "GET /healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 200 3 "-" "ELB-HealthChecker/2.0" "-"
```

I'm expecting a lot more timing info (which I just added).

For reference, this shows the default-detected Dockerfiles in the public images, but I don't consider it helpful here:

https://github.com/docker-library/repo-info/blob/master/repos/nginx/remote/latest.md

Comment: Please add the content of your `server.conf` file.

Comment: It's above. Depending on your setup, it will be called different things. Whatever we want to call it, it's above. Note that it has `http { }`, not `server { }`, and that it also imports the server-specific configs (implying that this is the root config).

Comment: Your Dockerfile references two nginx configuration files. I don't care how you name them, but you need to provide both.

Comment: server.conf attached.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `access_log` directive under `server` instead?
For me having `log_format` under `http` and `access_log` defined for server locations made the trick.